# How can I draw a circle in the middle of the canvas' parent in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx

From what I understand, the size of the canvas is determined by it's content unless otherwise specified.  My canvas is inside the center pane of a BorderPane.  The left pane is 15% of the window's width, which is 75% of the user's screen width.  So the remaining width of the center pane is 85% of the window width.  I want to draw a circle in the middle of this remaining 85% of the window width, or in other words in the center of the center pane.

Currently, the circle is off center to the right as far as width is concerned, but the height is correct.  What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
public Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    public double windowWidth = screenSize.getWidth() * .75;
    public double windowHeight = screenSize.getHeight() * .75;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();

        Button regenerate = new Button("Regenerate Board");
        regenerate.setPrefWidth(windowWidth * .15 * .80);
        regenerate.getStyleClass().add("spButton");

        Button settings = new Button("Game Settings");
        settings.setPrefWidth(windowWidth * .15 * .80);
        settings.getStyleClass().add("spButton");

        Button start = new Button("Start Game");
        start.setPrefWidth(windowWidth * .15 * .80);
        start.getStyleClass().add("spButton");

        VBox bpLeft = new VBox(20);
        bpLeft.setPrefWidth(windowWidth * .15);
        //bpLeft.resize(((screenSize.getWidth() * .75) *.20), screenSize.getHeight() * .75);
        bpLeft.getStyleClass().add("bpLeft");
        bpLeft.getChildren().addAll(regenerate, settings, start);

        root.setLeft(bpLeft);

        //Circle cir = new Circle();
        double originX = (windowWidth * .15) + ((windowWidth * .85) / 2);
        double originY = (windowHeight / 2);
        double radius = windowHeight * .90;
        /*cir.setCenterX(originX);
        cir.setCenterY(originY);
        cir.setRadius(windowHeight * (.90 / 2));        
        cir.setFill(Color.rgb(87, 175, 255));*/

        //Hexagon hex = new Hexagon(new Point((int)originX, (int)originY), 10);

        Pane wrapperPane = new Pane();
        root.setCenter(wrapperPane);
        // Put canvas in the center of the window
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas((int)Math.round(windowWidth * .85), (int)Math.round(windowHeight));
        root.setAlignment(canvas, Pos.CENTER_LEFT);

        GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
        drawCircle(gc, new Point((int)originX, (int)originY), (int)radius, true, true, 0x57AFFF, 3);
        wrapperPane.getChildren().add(canvas);

        //root.getChildren().add(btn);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, windowWidth, windowHeight);

        scene.getStylesheets().add(HelloWorld.class.getResource("Catan.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

}

public void drawCircle(GraphicsContext g, Point origin, int radius,
            boolean centered, boolean filled, int colorValue, int lineThickness) {
        g.setFill(Color.BLUE);
        g.fillOval(origin.x - (radius / 2), origin.y - (radius / 2), radius, radius);
    }
```

This is my current output:
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Surely you just want to center the circle in the canvas, instead of offsetting it in the canvas by 15% of the width of the window...? (As an aside, don't mix JavaFX and AWT when you don't have to. Use the [`Screen`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Screen.html) class to get the screen dimensions, instead of `java.awt.Toolkit`.)

Comment: Pretty much, yes.  Assuming that the canvas is the width of the center pane.

Comment: So why are you adding `windowWidth * 0.15` to the x-coordinate of the center of the circle?